# BeanCreationException in Spring Framework .WAR deploy to Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: spring, ubuntu, tomcat6, javabeans

I am in the process of switching from a Windows box to Ubunutu and I want to run my own local instance of Tomcat 6.  I have installed Tomcat 6 without any basic issues. When I try to deploy a `.war` file that I had running on the Tomcat 6 instance on my Windows box I am getting the following error....

```
Apr 26, 2010 3:30:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 26, 2010 3:30:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.ameren.eam.ldap.LdapDAONovellImpl] for bean with name 'testNovellDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ameren.eam.ldap.LdapDAONovellImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1249)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:612)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ameren.eam.ldap.LdapDAONovellImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1399)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:381)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1170)
    ... 40 more
```

The class that is not being found is located at `/WEB-INF/classes/com/ameren/eam/ldap/LdapDAONovellImpl.class` relative to `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`.  I cannot figure out why it cannot find the class?  Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Do you use the packaged version of tomcat? Who is running tomcat? How did you deploy your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the stock Ubuntu Tomcat, everything is locked down by the security manager by default.  Suggest you read this page:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html

and get a grasp on how it works.  You'll need to make changes to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy` file, granting access where your webapp is located on the filesystem.