# Tomcat - unable to open logs - unable to deploy

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, ubuntu

I am trying to **deploy a web app** on an Ubuntu system. The WAR is an **EXPLODED** folder. There are **no issues with build**. But I am unable to deploy to **Tomcat6 server**. Everything was working fine. **Same Code, Same files**. All of a sudden, unable to deploy.

The **main difference** I find now is that - **the logs** at /var/lib/tomcat6/logs - **localhost.2010-11-01.log is locked** and **can be opened only by root** user. Dont understand why?

Because of this issue, I am getting the following error (from localhost.2010-11-01.log):

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Is my issue related to

> [BeanCreationException in Spring Framework .WAR deploy to Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu 9.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716677/beancreationexception-in-spring-framework-war-deploy-to-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu-9-10)?

---

Update1:
The issue of Tomcat logs being readable by root user is gone now. However, these ERRORs remain.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.**BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name 'africa' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'antarctica' while setting bean property 'antarctica'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.**BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name 'antarctica' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'australia' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.**BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name 'australia' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
>    **Invocation of init method failed;** nested exception is **java.lang.Exception**: Unexpected line 
>   **Warning**:  mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server during query in ....  **#ERROR:Too Many Connections!**

Update 2:

> Just switched on my Ubuntu system. Only firefox running at the moment. No Eclipse or other software running. Did not shutdown or restart Tomcat. Just tried to launch the web app thru Tomcat Manager application (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) - the same thing I had been trying before.

**Result**: Web app gets launched with no issues!

I have absolutely **NO CLUE why this did not work before**. Also, **NO CLUE why it's working now**, if at all there was a serious issue. I WASTED one whole day :(.

Comment: Have you tried simply copying the exploded WAR folder to the 'webapps' directory under the Tomcat installation?

Comment: @Bernard: The WAR folder path has been correctly mentioned through an xml file in /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost - without having to copy to webapps folder. The same setup had been working before.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: how to check if its a permission issue? 
Also, I dont understand the root cause of the issue - as no code has been touched. Things were working fine.

Comment: @van make sure all the files in the exploded war are executable by whoever is the tomcat user.  You might want to try putting the war in the webapps dir, if it isn't there, like @bernard suggested.

Comment: when you say everything was working, do you mean on the same machine with the same setup, or do you mean the war deploys fine on other machines?

Comment: @hvgotcodes same machine with the same setup.

Comment: @hvgotcodes more than 1GB free space left.

Comment: @van, obviously something has changed.  we need to play detective until we find out what it is.  Did you rule out a permissions issue?  From the locked file clue, it sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: @van, also be sure to completely shutdown tomcat before restarting.

Comment: @hvgotcodes completely shutdown tomcat before restarting - does that mean "/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh" or "sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start" or something else?

Comment: @van either should work.  you should use ps aex | grep java to make sure that all  java processes are stopped.  Im wondering if tomcat is still running and has locked a file.  Also, try following @bernard suggestion for diagnostic purposes.  If neither of those work, try downloading the tomcat zip, unzipping in your home directory, and deploying there.  Maybe the system tomcat instance is hosed.

Comment: Is this something to do with it (Update 1) `Warning: mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server during query in .... #ERROR:Too Many Connections!`?  Did you have this working previously?  Did you run a system update recently (apt-get, synaptic, etc...)?

Comment: @Robin everything was working fine. No system update done recently.

Answer (score 0):

if you set-up logging like so: [Tomcat startup logs - SEVERE: Error filterStart how to get a stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016808/tomcat-startup-logs-severe-error-filterstart-how-to-get-a-stack-trace/6081748#6081748)

Then at least you will get the stack trace.